# Get OS or Platform of the device in Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

The question is *is there any trick to get the platform of the client through a bot in Telegram in any way or not?* For example, I wanna know the platform of the user which is in ios, Android or Desktop without asking from the user?

Comment: i think it is not possible via bot api. but you can send a dedicated link to each user to click and send him/her to browser and save his/her data.

Comment: Botan.io provide needed feature. like device platform, locations, ect

Answer (score 1):

If you read at Telegram Bot API is no there information about OS platform, specifically in the Available Types section you cannot see any property named platform or OS.

You just receive a JSON (from Telegram servers) with essential data like user_id, update_id, type of data: depending if the message was action from callback or inline query, or message come from channel, group or private message, the content say if the message is a text, file, image, video, voice or audio, etc. But not the platform.